# does PendingIntent can get a class as a parameter?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, push-notification

I tried to refactor gcmRegisterer from an Activity to a class.

But now I see the sendPushMessage method.

Does `GcmRegisterer` has to be an Activity ?

in order to send the PendingIntent?

```
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, GcmRegisterer.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you're using `PendingIntent.getActivity` yes it needs to be an activity. But you also have the option to use `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` to send a broadcast that you can listen to using a `BroadcastReceiver` or `PendingIntent.getService` to start a service.

Which one to use really depends on what you want to happen when the user clicks on the notification.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , You have to make a class of GcmRegisterer which extend Activity